# PHP JSON Array Objects adding 0 as key

Tags: php, json

UPDATED QUESTION

Here is my class...

```
class EbayItem
{
    public $ebayItemId;
}
```

Right before my foreach loop, I have the following:

```
$mainResponse = array();
$mainResponse = [
    [
        "ack" => "success",
    ],
    "result" => []
    ];
```

Inside of my loop, I have...

```
$ebayItem = new EbayItem();
$ebayItem->ebayItemId = $itemId;
array_push($mainResponse['result'], $ebayItem);
```

Right after my loop I have...

```
echo json_encode($mainResponse);
```

This will produce the following:

```
{"0":{"ack":"success"},"result":[{"ebayItemId":{"0":"153532419741"}}]}
```

I need it to produce...

```
{"ack": "success","result": [{"ebayItemId": "153532419741","ebayItemTitle": "..."}]}
```

Comment: You never created the `result` container in the `$mainResponse`, and you're pushing directly onto `$mainResponse` instead of the `result` container you should have created.

Comment: Your "desired result" is not valid JSON

Comment: So you're pushin item to array without providing a key, what did you expect?

Comment: What is the structure of `MyItem()`?

Comment: The `"":{"0":"153532419741"}` must be coming from `MyItem` as it's not added in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

---

> ```
> [{"ack":"success"},"result": [{"ItemId":153532419741,...},{...}]]
> ```

This is not valid JSON.

- Objects (`{}`) contain `"key": value` pairs.
- Arrays (`[]`) contain an ordered list of values.

You can't have a key (`"result"`) in an array.

---

re edit:

> ```
> {{"ack":"success"},"result":[{"ebayItemId":"153532419741"}]}
> ```

You can't have a value without a key in an object either.

Comment: maybe instead of saying what I cant have, what about advising what I can do.

Comment: @soldfor You keep saying that you _need_ your code to produce these certain invalid strings.  Perhaps you should show the code that is _consuming_ this result so that we can show you what the correct JSON should be

Comment: i have a typo in my json, that was my fault. I updated my question with expected output which is correct json